# Qual versão do ItextSharp

Tags: itextsharp

Bom Dia, Pessoal
Qual versão do ItextSharp posso baixar para usar no Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 para asp net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê preferência sempre a última versão das bibliotecas que estiver usando. Se isso não for lhe causar nenhum problema de incompatibilidade, é claro.

A última versão disponível no Nuget do [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/) é a **5.5.7**.

Para colocá-la em seu projeto você só precisa ir até o *Package Manager Console* e digitar

> PM> install-package iTextSharp

Comment: JBueno, fico grato por estar-me orientando, vou seguir suas orientações, obrg, abraço